# Redirect https to http except sign-in page

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect, drupal-7

I need to redirect all the pages of my website from `https` to `http` except `sign-in` page. I want if someone try to browse `sign-in` page via `http`, it should be redirected to `https`. My website is developed under drupal 7. However, I have written some condition in `.htaccess` but no luck. What I did as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sign-in
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

By the above code all the page are redirecting `https` to `http` but not getting exception for `sign-in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep these 2 redirect rules at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect anything except /sign-in to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/sign-in [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# redirect /sign-in to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /sign-in [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: If I do this, for some reason my fonts get loaded over https (on http sign-in) and I get CORS errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry no idea why there would be any CORS errors due to `http -> http`

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sign-in\.php$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule ^(sign-in\.php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: no luck my friend ... it redirects to all the page `http://domain.name/index.php`. Do know where I am doing wrong